# How do I obtain the following format of clustered bar graph in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2007

I have data from a study with three independent variables (IV1 with two conditions, IV2 and IV3 with four conditions each) and one dependent variable.

I would like to obtain a clustered (not stacked) bar graph in the following format.

[image] The data is first grouped into different levels of IV1, then into different levels of IV2, then into different levels of IV3.

How would I do this in Excel?

Comment: Did my answer help you or not?

Comment: It did, thank you! I tried to upvote it, but my vote doesn't display because my rep is <15. I did mark it green just now though.

Comment: FWIW, quickly accepting an answer lessens the likelihood that other (possibly better) answers will be submitted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest solution I could think of is using a pivot graph.

- You sort your data in 4 columns. One for IV1, one for IV2, one for IV3 and then one for the dependent variable.
- Then you select the data (including headers) and insert a pivot graph.
- When this is done, you add drag the IV fields to the categories box and the dependent variable to the sum-values box.

What you will get is a graph that looks like this:

[image]

Comment: This is very helpful - would you happen to know how to also add color coding to this graph? So that the individual levels of IV3 are colored uniquely.

Comment: @genericity It is possible by selecting the series and then adjusting the format. But it gives random colors to your graph, not like the ones in your question. I tried searching for a solution for that, but haven't come up with one. Maybe someone else on here knows how to make them be a different shade of the same color.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how to get the colors the way you want them.

Add a column to your data like this: the column "color" has a different value for each color you will use, with the first four rows having a value of 1, the next four a value of 2, etc.

[image: Preliminary Data]

Make your pivot chart with IV1 through IV3 in the rows area, Value in the Values area, and Color in the Columns area. Each different color (each block) has its values in a different column.

[image: Pivot Table]

Make a pivot chart; each column of values gets a different series in the chart, so you can format bars in each block the same, and format distinct blocks differently. Select any one of the bar chart series so that the Series Overlap is 100% and the gap width is something small, like 25%.

[image: Pivot Chart with Different Color Blocks]